# Windows CE 4.2 .NET and RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-ce

We have severeal thin clients with Windows CE 4.2 .NET installed, however on this one there is no RDP.

I've seen that it should come with RDP. How do I use it in the 4.2 (where can I get it)?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to look for updates that bring RDP, I've seen [an update for 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18111) that does include RDP. But I don't know about earlier versions. I guess you aren't able to [just download Remote Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=856) meant for the normal Windows?

Comment: The normal RDP does not work in Windows CE versions, I have tried downloading it. It seems i need a specific RDP to run in the CE.

Comment: @user895822: if you have other terminals that do have Remote Desktop then why not just copy the program from one of them? I suspect the application is in the Windows directory. You first need to make sure they are similar systems though. Windows CE can run on lots of different hardware (e.g. ARM, MIPS) and normal programs will only run on a specific architecture.

Comment: Thats the first thing that crossed my mind, if I had the application (RDP) in any of them, which I dont since they're all the same copies. This is my thin client config: Processor: National Semicondutor Corp., Geode GXm 266mhz, 128mb RAM 32mb Compact Flash. OS: Windows CE .NET 4.2 (Compile 1088)

Comment: I've found this: http://code.google.com/p/rdesktop-ce/downloads/list - Its a Remote Desktop project for Windows CE and Mobile. I havent tried this yet, will post back results